# Is_granted method return error on Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.3

I am learning Symfony 4 and trying to use is_granted method in twig but unfortunately it return errors:

```
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\VoteEvent::__construct() must be of the type int, null given, called in /var/www/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/Voter/TraceableVoter.php on line 41
```

Here is my code

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
{% endif %}
```

I have no knowledge with voter yet but want to use is_granted method only? what is the problem here?

Any help would be extremely appreciated?

Comment: technically there shouldn't be a problem. Did you add a voter yourself?

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30675 : A Voter's `vote()`method did not have a a `return`.

Comment: @AlisterBulman put your comment as answer, I will vote it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar point here: http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30675  A Voter's `vote()` method did not have a a `return`, which is used to create a `VoteEvent`.

Comment: yeah the tutor give uncompleted VoterExample in the beginning and become a problem later